# How can I check how many containers are running a certain docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to check how many containers are running an image, I could do that using `docker ps --filter ancestor ="imagename"` and then count the number of containers.But my machine does not support this command is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How about

```
docker ps | grep imagename | wc -l
```

Answer (score 30):

The accepted answer didnt work for me nor did https://stackoverflow.com/users/2915097/user2915097

So I kinda tweaked it;

```
 docker ps -q | wc -l
```

All the answers basically try to get the list and do a line count.

Comment: this should be accepted answer

Comment: FYI, what I do all the time when starting up...
watch eval "docker ps -q | wc -l"

Answer (score 3):

Can you use something like

`docker inspect --format='{{.Container.Spec.Image}}' $(docker ps -q)` and test the image returned by this command?

UPDATE:
How about combining this with the accepted answer (as of Mar-2022)? Into something like this:
`docker inspect --format='{{.Config.Image}}' $(docker ps -q) | grep imagename | wc -l`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
docker ps -f ancestor="imagename" --format '{{.Names}}' | wc -l
```

If you want to print the containers info and then the count

```
docker ps -f ancestor="imagename" --format '{{.Names}}' | tee >(wc -l)
```

Comment: it does not work for me I am using ubuntu and 3 containers are running it still shows 0 containers